# How to merge two files from different folders base on few character match in files name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have two folders with text files, i want to read files from first folder and check in second folder if some specfic character matched in files name then merge on column 'Time' , do this for several files

```
folder 1:
  07k0ms_610s_hh85m_sq150_t40k0_sn183_0
  08k0ms_610s_hh85m_sq150_t40k0_sn183_20
  011k0ms_610s_hh85m_sq150_t40k0_sn183_-10
folder 2:
   07k0m_t40k0_try-0.2
   08k0m_t40k0_try-0.2
   32k0m_t40k0_try-0.2

read file from folder 1 and check if 07k0m_t40k0 or 08k0m_t40k0 or 11k0m_t40k0 match in file name then folder two file merge in folder 1 file and save in csv one by one
```

Comment: what hav you tried?

Comment: @DrBwts  don't understand what should try, thats why asked here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

lst_folders = ['folder_1',
               'folder_2']

lst_str_find = ['07k0m_t40k0', '08k0m_t40k0', '11k0m_t40k0']


lst_files_1 = sorted(glob.glob(lst_folders[0]+'/*.txt'))
lst_files_2 = sorted(glob.glob(lst_folders[1]+'/*.txt'))

for file_1 in lst_files_1:
    str_search = file_1[file_1.find("/")+1:file.find("s_")]

    if any([(str_search in i) for i in lst_str_find]):

        for file_2 in lst_files_2:

            if file_name in file_2:
                print(file_1)
                print(file_2)

                # here load,merge and save file_1 & file_2 - the specific code
                # depends on the structure of your files and the way you want
                # to import them. Should look similar to:
                # 
                # merge_1 =  pd.read_csv(file_1)
                # merge_2 =  pd.read_csv(file_2)
                # merged_file = pd.concat([merge_1, merge_2])
                # merged_file.to_csv (lst_folders[0]+'/merged_'+str_search+'.csv', index=None)
```

Notes:

- read/merge/write might need to be adjusted, depending on the actual 
  structure of your files, which did not become clear from your post
- the code assumes that it lives in the same directory as the folders. If that is not the case, the paths must be adjusted accordingly

Let me know, if it worked :)